# Refresh/reload a dropdown list after removing values with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, cascade

The following code removes dropdown list values based on text entered in a textbox.

## FIDDLE DEMO

**JQUERY**

```js
var ddl = ('#ddl'),
  txt = ('#txt');

$(txt).change(function() {   
  var x = $(txt).val(),
    li = $(ddl).html();

  if (x.length != 0) {
    $(ddl).html(li);
    $(ddl + ' :not([value="' + x + '"])').remove();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txt" type="text" placeholder="Enter a number...">

<select id="ddl">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">Select...</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

### QUESTION

How to restore dropdownlist values back to initial state when a new value is entered into the textbox?

I have been attempting to use:

```
$(ddl).selectmenu("refresh");
```

but this stops the script from working as expected.

Comment: This is redundant: `var li = $(ddl).html(); $(ddl).html(li);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so

```
    ...
    $(ddl).html(li);
    $(ddl + ' :not([value="' + x + '"])').hide();
} else {
    $(ddl + ' :not([value="' + x + '"])').show();
}
...
```

Instead of removing the item completely, you simply hide. When you empty the input field, re-show all the items.

Comment: I've been working on this all day!  Thank you!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var ddl = ('#ddl'),
    txt = ('#txt');

$(txt).change(function () {
    var x  = $(txt).val(),
        li = $(ddl).html();

    $(ddl + ' option').show();

    if (x.length != 0) {     
        $(ddl).html(li);
        $(ddl + ' option:not([value="' + x + '"])').hide();
        $(ddl + ' option[value="' + x + '"]').prop('selected',true);
    }
});
```